# Raspberry Pi won't connect to NAS Server

Tags: samba, fstab

I can't connect to my local NAS from my Raspberry Pi, and yet, on my Mac I can using the old Cmd+K.

So far, I've tried several options, including :

- `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD // 192.168.X.X /mnt/` which tries to connect as `root`;
- `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD // 192.168.X.X/USERNAME /mnt/`  which does the same, except with my private user (that's the point!);
- in `sudo nano /etc/fstab`, I've tried `//192.168.X.X/USERNAME /mnt/ cifs username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD 0 0` (also tried using the credentials in a file inside my `/home/PI_USER/` directory) and changing `//192.168.X.X/USERNAME` to `//192.168.X.X:/USERNAME`;

**Encountered errors**

I am getting any of those depending of the command :

- `Unable to find suitable address`
- `mount error: could not resolve address for 192.168.X.X:: Unknown error` (so helpful!)
- or simply listing a the Usage for the `mount` command

Whenever I run `sudo tail -f /var/log/kern.log`, I get :

- `CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.`
- `CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/ retur code = -113`

**Notes :**

- I've tried rebooting as well as `sudo mount -a` to try to connect;
- I am running on a fresh installation of a PI with `samba`, `samba-client` and `samba-common-bin` installed;
- I have double, triple and quadruple checked my login information and paths;
- Contrary to several tutorials I've found, I do not need to create a NAS server from the Pi, I need it to be a client;
- I can ping my server with 0% packet loss

Comment: `-f` is fake mount. You probably meant `-t`. Is that a typo in the question?

Comment: @LjmDullaart yes, it was simply a typo, just fixed it. I am still however getting error messages.

Comment: You say you installes `samba-client`; in my installations that would be `smbclient`. Did you install  `cifs-utils` as well?

Comment: Is it a (relatively) new NAS? Do you know which version of CIFS/SMB the NAS is running? Could you try adding that version number to the fstab-line?
`//isengard  /media/isengard  cifs  uid=0,credentials=/home/tim/.smb,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,noperm 0 0`

Comment: It would help if you connected the commands and the error messages more directly. As in `sudo mount -t ` etc gives the following error message: ....

Comment: It turns out you found the issue with the wrong package. Thanks, mate! I've given you credit in and answer. Thanks!

Comment: Normally, you would accept the answer. That gives me the possibility to give some background information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`samba-client` is a so-called virtual package. From the FAQ:

> > Debian GNU/Linux FAQ
> >
> > 6.8 What is a Virtual Package?
> >
> > A virtual package is a generic name that applies to any one of a group of packages, all of which provide similar basic functionality. For example, both the tin and trn programs are news readers, and should therefore satisfy any dependency of a program that required a news reader on a system, in order to work or to be useful. They are therefore both said to provide the "virtual package" called news-reader.

In this case, `smbclient` provides the virtual package`samba-client`. However, installing `samba-client` will not install `smbclient` as it dependency.

In this case, installing the real package (`smbclient`) provides the solution.